# How do I solve $z+z^{-1}=2\bar z$ using $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z =x-iy$ substitution?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics, education

How do I solve $z+z^{-1}=2\bar z$ using $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z =x-iy$ substitution?

zconjugate is also $\bar z$ in some countries.

Comment: would you like to share what you have obtained so far?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I edited your post to make the $\LaTeX$ right.  The page linked by Lord Shark the Unknown in his comment helps.  Welome to MSE!  Cheers!

Comment: The property $|z|^{2} = \bar{z}z$ it might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for editing my post! My computer does'nt allow latex so i have to type my questions like this unfortunately
and thanks for the link!

Comment: "Using $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z =x-iy$ substitution" leads to possibly the most complicated and less illuminating solution (basically everything else works better). Sure this method is imposed?

Comment: What would be the easiest method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

$z = x + iy, \tag 1$

we have

$z^{-1} = \dfrac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2}; \tag 2$

thus the equation

$z + z^{-1} = 2 \bar z \tag 3$

becomes

$x + iy +  \dfrac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2} = 2x -2iy, \tag 4$

or

$x + \dfrac{x}{x^2 + y^2} + i \left (y - \dfrac{y}{x^2 + y^2} \right ) = 2x - 2iy; \tag 5$

if we equate the real and imagiary parts from the two sides of this equation, we find

$x + \dfrac{x}{x^2 + y^2} = 2x, \tag 6$

$y - \dfrac{y}{x^2 + y^2} = -2y; \tag 7$

whence

$\dfrac{x}{x^2 + y^2} = x, \tag 8$

$\dfrac{y}{x^2 + y^2} = 3y; \tag 9$

if $x \ne 0$, (8) implies

$x^2 + y^2 = 1; \tag{10}$

this makes $y \ne 0$ impossible, since

$y \ne 0 \Longrightarrow x^2 + y^2 = \dfrac{1}{3}; \tag{11}$

so one set of solutions is

$x^2 = 1, \; y = 0, \tag{12}$

or

$x = \pm 1, \; y = 0 \Longrightarrow z = \pm 1, \tag{13}$

which is easily checked.  A similar argument shows that we may also have

$x = 0, \; y = \pm \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{3}, \tag{15}$

or

$z = \pm  \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{3} i, \tag{16}$

also easily checked; thus the complete list of solutions is

$z = -1, z = 1, z = \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{3} i, z = -\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{3} i. \tag{17}$

Comment: A good answer with explanation and more details +1.

Comment: So, x is also equal to these extra two solutions?

Comment: @Nosrati thank you my friend!

Comment: @KaylaMartin: yes you can check all four values of $z$!

Comment: Great, this helped a lot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

if $z\neq0$ then
$$z+\dfrac{1}{z}=2\bar z$$
$$z^2+1=2z\bar{z}=2|z|^2$$
$$x^2-y^2+2ixy+1=2(x^2+y^2)$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-y^2+1&=2(x^2+y^2)\\
2xy&=0.
\end{cases}
Only $x=0$ or $y=0$ should occur.

Can you continue?

Comment: Yes that looks good, just out of curiosity, how would you do this question by using demoivres substitution? I dont understand how because the modulus r is out the front and this question doesnt use numbers, so would you just substitute in (costheta+isintheta) for z?

Comment: yes, usually de Moiivier used in cases with power $>1$, like $z^n$

Comment: yes dear . . . .

Comment: Could you take a look at the solution commented below by Robert Lewis. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint: $\;z+\frac{1}{z}=2\bar z \;\;\iff\;\; z^2 - 2 z \bar z + 1 = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; z^2 =  2 |z|^2 - 1 \in \mathbb{R}\,$.

The square of a complex number is real iff the number is either real, or purely imaginary. This leaves two cases to consider for $\,z=x \in \mathbb{R}\,$ and $\,z = i y \in i\mathbb{R}\,$.